# Novel where a man reincarnates after destroying his world, then kills his new family, then kills everyone in a sect he joins

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is either a Korean, Japanese or Chinese novel.

In it, the male protagonist cultivates to become so powerful that he destroys/kills his whole world subsequently drawing the wrath of a heavenly tribulation which in turn kills him. He then reincarnates into another world into a pretty rich family. Since he actually older than what he seems, his family is creeped out by him and his coldness. He eventually kills his family then joins a sect. He enters the sect as an outer discipline killing his way into the inner sect. He then proceeds to kill and slaughter everybody in and out his sect. He is eventually discovered and misunderstood to be an elder of the sect who took control of a younger person body. When in reality he actually an all powerful cultivator from another world who destroyed his own world.